# How to hide the entire Ext.selection.CheckboxModel in ExtJS grid

Tags: extjs

I need to hide the entire column of the check box (Ext.selection.CheckboxModel). I found out to get the columns of the grid to hide, but the columns does not give the checkbox column.

Comment: Are you using the `getColumnModel` method of the grid to try and hide said column ?

Comment: i used grid.columns to get all the columns, but checkbox is not one of the column. Using grid.getColumnModel() gives undefined function. May be its not available in extjs ver 4.1.1

Comment: Yes, it's deprecated now I believe which is why I was asking since I don't know which version you are using. So you are saying that you cannot hide a column that has checkboxes in it ? Can you edit your question with a screenshot of what happens ?

Comment: I am saying i cannot hide a column which is created by Ext.selection.CheckboxModel

Answer (score 2):

`grid.headerCt.items.getAt(0).hide()`

Comment: Doing that only hides the first column after checkbox column in my grid, not the checkbox column. The grid format is checkbox column, then other columns.

Comment: Checkbox selection model places checkboxes in the first column, hence getAt(0). However, you can hide any column the above way, just use another index: 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: If i use getAt(0)..Its getting the column after the checkbox column.

Comment: Which Ext version? I've tested here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html

Comment: i am using ext version 4.1.1

Comment: There must be something else wrong. If I navigate to http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html and type `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1].headerCt.items.getAt(0).hide()` in the console, the column with checkboxes gets hidden as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in 4.2.2.  I used a combination of the other answer by Saki and a little traversing through the DOM because the "getAt0).hide()" solution did not work for me either:

```
grid.headerCt.items.items[0].hidden = true;
```